# OpenLayers 5 add conditional style to Text

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5

I am trying to add conditionally styled text to vector object that I am placing on the map.

I have a service that creates the "Style" that looks like this

```
let myStyle = new Style(
    {
        fill: new Fill({color: Shade}),
        stroke: new Stroke({color: 'black',width:1}),
        text: new Text({text:Label})

    })
```

This works but I can't seem to figure out how to conditionally style and show/hide based on resolution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make it a style function, for example:

```
let myStyle = function(feature, resolution) {
  if (resolution < myCondition) {
    return new Style(
      {
        fill: new Fill({color: Shade}),
        stroke: new Stroke({color: 'black',width:1}),
        text: new Text({text:Label})

      });
  }
}
```